# How to include figures below the beginning of section?

Tags: graphics

I am writing a paper and have included a separate section at the end called "Tables and Graphs" but when I insert an image below the \section{ }, it pushes the title of the section below it.
My code is:

```
\newpage
\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\section{Tables and Graphs}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{"Provincial Time Series growth".png}
\caption{Natural Logarithm of Provincial Real GDP per capita, 1960-2016}
\end{figure}
```

Which produces the following image:

[image]

Not sure why it is doing this. When I don't include the image the title just appears at the top of the page. Anyone see a clear issue with my code or is there something more I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing a location marker like this `\begin{figure}[H]` would be able to solve the problem.